Orbital perturbation
I originally asked this on the physics stack, but I'm never good at knowing exactly which one to use, so I'll post here as recommended there.
I'm totally an amateur when it comes to mathematics, but for overly nitpicky storytelling reasons, I really want to figure how to have multiple bodies in a solar system without any of their orbits changing, specifically regarding eccentricity.
Specifically, I want one planet in an eccentric orbit, and one with nearly zero eccentricity, so that I can have one habitable world and one like Io or Europa due to the raised eccentricity (they're both orbiting a white dwarf).
Is there a formula out there to determine when a body's proximity, eccentricity, mass, etc. affect the orbit of another?

"A formula to determine when a body's proximity, eccentricity, mass, etc. affect the orbit of another": It is a very simple formula: they always do. For example, Jupiter does influence the orbit of the Earth. For a numerical example, see the Orbital Eccentricity section of the Wikipedia article on Milankovitch cycles. The point is that you need to decide before hand how large can the perturbations be and still be considered small enough to be acceptable, and then do a simulation of the evolution of the system.

You really should pick one forum or the other and delete one version. This query is a duplicate of this question

@elemtilas Sorry. Deleted

I may be wrong, I'm by no interpretation a celestial machinist, but if someone asked me a comparable question concerning electronics.... Computers are employed to simulate the possibilities of orbits because there isn't one simple equation. I suspect you didn't get answers on [physics.se] because everyone was wondering how to explain that you're missing the four years of college needed to understand why you won't receive an answer. Like I said, I could be wrong (I hope I am!)... but it feels like I'm not. What would you do if the math says you can't have the orbits you want?

@JBH -- We need better physics.

@JBH I would be a little sad but also glad for being a bit more informed!

@Kazon To make a point: we often get folks on this stack who are way over concerned with "realistic" and "scientific." The universe regularly astounds astronomers by presenting as a reality something previously believed to be impossible. As an engineer I've lived through a period of time where we knew, we knew, that something was both mathematically and realistically impossible - only to have Lawrence Berkley National Labs do it. I personally think it's a waste of time to ask if something's possible. Just do it - and act cool when the universe proves you right in the face of your detractors.

Welcome to the Three Body Problem!
I am sorry to inform you, that current physics has not yet found a perfect solution to solve the question you asked forever without having good starting data. You need to simulate iteratively for most configurations, such as the solar system.
Under some edge conditions it can devolve into two two-body problems, when the secondary bodies of either are far enough from one another to deem that they do not influence one another, or where one two-body problem circles the other as a combined item, but that only holds true for extremely narrow situations and sometimes even only short timescales. Think... Earth+Moon around Sun.
Under some configurations, you might find stable patterns.

Dynamic systems governed by gravity in which there are more than 2 interacting bodies are often chaotic.
This doesn't mean that they cannot be stable for a short period of time, or that their behavior cannot be predicted to a certain extent.
A measure of how chaotic a system is is the so called Lyapunov time:

In mathematics, the Lyapunov time is the characteristic timescale on which a dynamical system is chaotic. The Lyapunov time mirrors the limits of the predictability of the system. By convention, it is defined as the time for the distance between nearby trajectories of the system to increase by a factor of e.

In layman terms, the Lyapunov time tells you how far in time you can make reliable predictions on the behavior of the system.
For your reference, the solar system has a Lyapunov time of 50 million years.
Since gravity is a force with infinite range, you cannot avoid having reciprocal perturbations once you start putting more bodies into your system. How these perturbations play out on the long run is way beyond a simple formula accessible to a self professed totally amateur mathematician. Dynamic systems are governed by differential equations which haunt students of technical and scientific universities.
And unless you plan to tell your story to an audience of ill disposed physicists, you will hardly need to explain all the details in your story to make it enjoyable.

often chaotic - there are a few stable patterns that can be created.

@Trish: There are entire classes of multi-body systems which are stable or at least bounded.

@AlexP Yes, that is why I said often, which is in contrast to the claim of the answer that more than 2 interacting bodies are (implied: always) chaotic.

Sorry for posting a somewhat non-hard-science answer. I'm posting it mostly to address deficiencies in other non-hard-science answers.
Ignore the answers referring to the three body problem, it's not relevant. This is because you're asking about two planets orbiting a star, i.e. the mass of one of the three bodies is much greater than the other two, and that makes it much easier, otherwise we wouldn't be able to predict orbits in our own Solar system.
I think what you want is easily feasible. Generally speaking, having a body on a highly eccentric orbit will result in a lot of tidal friction, and that dissipation will tend to circularise the orbit over time.
Similarly, the two small bodies can exert tidal forces on each other, and as those get dissipated it can lead to orbital resonances.
I don't think you need to worry about the second issue too much unless you want to, because the tidal forces between two rocky planets orbiting a star are not that great. You just need to have their orbits not very close to each other, because one planet is closer to the star, or maybe because they don't orbit in the same plane.
To get around the first issue, you could just say that one of the bodies wasn't always in its current orbit. Eventually its orbit will circularise but that hasn't happened yet because it's only been in its current orbit for a million years or so. This will mean it has very severe tides as on Io, but that's what you wanted.
To explain the orbit, perhaps you could say that it was originally a binary planet (or a planet and a moon), but due to a gravitational interaction with some other body, one of the planets was sent into the star and the other one boosted out to a higher, and more eccentric, orbit.
